# C# update stored procedure not making changes to database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have looked at similar topics with no luck, it looks (to me) like im doing things correctly but the database is just not being updated.

My function, as below, has the parameter values of 1, "Connor Smith", 5, "New" respectively

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UpdateDevelopmentRequest(int changeID, string evaluator, int priority, string status)
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.DevRequests.UpdateDevRequest, Conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@changeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = changeID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@evaluator", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = evaluator;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@priority", SqlDbType.Int).Value = priority;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = status;

        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@changeID", changeID);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@evaluator", evaluator);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", priority);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);

        Conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Conn.Close();

        return RedirectToAction("DevelopmentRequests");
}
```

My stored procedure is as below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateDevRequests]
    @changeID INT,
    @evaluator NVARCHAR(30),
    @priority INT,
    @status NVARCHAR(15)
AS
    UPDATE it_ChangeRequest
    SET it_ChangeRequest.Evaluator = @evaluator, 
        it_ChangeRequest.Status = @status, 
        it_ChangeRequest.Priority = @priority
    WHERE ChangeID = @changeID
```

Aside from the code and stored procedure as shown, I have tried to add

```
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

which returned a 1 when values were correct and a 0 when they were incorrect (I am only expecting 1 row to be changed). I have also ran the query separately, hardcoding the values in e.g `Declare @changeID int = 1` and the query worked fine with this method too.

I have been stumped on this all morning and would appreciate some help

e: I also tried setting the stored procedure to just `priority = 2` instead of `priority = @priority` to ensure it was pointed and updating the expected DB and all worked as expected when doing that

Comment: What is your connectionstring? Are you sharing the same SqlConnection between multiple actions? This is well know to produce bugs and other problems in a web application where you cannot ensure to always be on the same thread that creates the connection

Comment: @Steve My ConnString has been used across multiple methods and works fine on them all, just not in updating this one. All the other methods read data.

Comment: Are you using DataDirectory in that connectionstring?

Comment: Are there any triggers on `it_ChangeRequest`?

Comment: You have some challenges in your code here. You need to wrap the connection and command objects in a USING statement. Also, you should not use the sp_ prefix. It is reserved for MS. Either use a different prefix or even better none at all. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix For the issue at hand, do you have a row in the table with Change_ID 1?

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`  returns a value.  If it's more than zero, the query worked.  Examine the value.

Comment: @SeanLange I would prefer to do something different in regards to the prefix, we are working on fixing things like this at the moment but best practice was avoided for a long time here :p There is a row with ChangeID = 1

Comment: @Steve Nope, not that I can tell

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко Nope, no triggers

Comment: @LarsTech this is why its confusing me, everything points towards the query having worked, but it just doesn't seem to reflect that when looking at the database

Comment: I can only say if ExecuteNonQuery returns not zero then you have updated the row, probably not in the same database where you are looking at.

Comment: Is there a chance for some TransactionScope to be running which is not commited ?

Comment: @Steve I thought this may be the case too, however something I tried and forgot to include in the original post is that I also tried setting the stored procedure to just `priority = 2` instead of `priority = @priority`, this updated the expected database so it seems its pointed in the correct direction

Comment: @ConnorSmith Steve asked a very important question and you brushed it aside.  "It works with all other queries that only select rows" might be an important clue.  Related to that question - how are you checking to see if your database was updated? Do you run the app, close it, and then use another tool (like SSMS) to query the same database? Does your connection string use the DataDirectory substitution string?

Comment: @ConnorSmith would it be possible for you to launch sql profiler and see the parameters that are sent to stored procedure? Perhaps WHERE ChangeID = @ changeID is returning 0 records.

Comment: @SMor in which comment is the question I brushed aside, I can not see it and I didn't intentionally do that.. I have a webpage that reads and displays everything in the DB, I've also gone into SSMS and checked via select statement on the row that should be affected. I don't quite understand what is meant by DataDirectory substitution string but I don't believe it's using that.

Comment: @sam Hi Sam, I am unable to give this a try at this point today however I will attempt it in the morn and get back asap - I haven't seen the SqlProfiler before so I haven't attempted using that but will try to. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your POST action as below by specifying ParameterDirection:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult UpdateDevelopmentRequest(int changeID, string evaluator, int priority, string status)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(<your_connection_string_goes_here>))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.DevRequests.UpdateDevRequest, Conn))
        {           
             cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

             /*
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@changeID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = changeID;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@evaluator", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = evaluator;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@priority", SqlDbType.Int).Value = priority;
             cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = status;
             */

             var param1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@changeID", changeID);
             cmd.Parameters["@changeID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
             param1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
             var param2 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@evaluator", evaluator);
             cmd.Parameters["@evaluator"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
             param2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
             var param3 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", priority);
             cmd.Parameters["@priority"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
             param3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
             var param4 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
             cmd.Parameters["@status"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
             param4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar

             Conn.Open();
             // If you want you can specify the Timeout as below
             // cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             Conn.Close();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("DevelopmentRequests");
    }
```

Comment: Why switch the properly defined parameters to use AddWithValue? That is a step backwards for them. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ And varchar should ALWAYS have the size defined.

Comment: Have just attempted this, the problem persists

Comment: @SeanLange I switched just to specify the parameter direction. Because, as far as I know, the other approach does not let you to define direction easily. No other reason.

Comment: @ConnorSmith would it be possible for you to launch sql profile and see the parameters that are sent to stored procedure?

Comment: Well all these parameters are input parameters, that is the default so no need to be explicit here. You can add a new parameter in the Add method. cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter([Many Constructors Here Including Direction]));

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for letting me know. Please feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @ConnorSmith did you get a chance of finding out what parameters have been sent to stored proc from c#?